# sql - incorrect total using SUM of DATEDiff results

Tags: sql, sql-server

when i run `DateDiff(dd, value1, value2)` it returns a lists of values

`56, 90, 61, 61, 58, 70, 193, 28, 143, 143, 0, 146` which totals **1360** (i've checked in excel)

However, when i use `SUM(DateDiff(dd, value1, value2))` i am returned the value **1459**

I have tried running the `SUM` code on a few different lists, and comparing the manually total values obtained by the first method. Sometimes the `SUM` value is higher, sometime lower, and there doesn't seem to be any relationship/ratio.

any ideas? thanks.

Comment: When I sum the values you listed, I get 1049: `SELECT 56+90+61+61+58+70+193+28+143+143+0+146 --1049`

Comment: @JamesParish Is there anything you can add to this question. I've tested using SUM on DATEDIFF and seems to be working. Does it work with smaller list of values? Could you provide some sample dates that don't work?

Comment: There is a remote possibility that the grouping you're adding when you do SUM could be doing something inadvertent. Can you put in the entire query?